# How to load thrift client in Erlang

Tags: erlang, thrift, scribe

I wish to use scribe to export some data from a Erlang application, but I have a problem with running Thrift client. I install Thrift, in the erlang lib directory. I'm using: thrift-0.6.1

I found some example code to connect from erlang via thrift to scribe:

```
{ok, C} = thrift_client:start_link("localhost", 1463, scribe_thrift, 
                                     [{strict_read, false}, 
                                      {strict_write, false}, 
                                      {framed, true}]),
```

but erlang is returning this error:

```
** exception error: undefined function thrift_client:start_link/4
```

When I try to run `application:start(thrift)`, for a moment I see some code completion for `thrift*`

```
7> thrift_client:
   call/3         close/1        module_info/0  module_info/1  new/2          
   send_call/3
```

and there is no method `start_link`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these days you want something like `thrift_client_util:new(Host, Port, ProtoModule, Options)`

which in your case would be:

```
thrift_client_util:new("localhost", 1463, scribe_thrift,
                       [{strict_read, false}, 
                        {strict_write, false}, 
                        {framed, true}]).
```

And an important point to bear in mind with the thrift API in erlang is that all calls return you a new client state value which you must use for subsequent calls. Using a client state value twice leads to wailing and the gnashing of teeth.

Comment: the observation from the answer of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718811/why-does-the-hbase-thrift-api-always-return-a-thrift-client-connection) shows that the returned client state is the same as the original one.

Answer (score 3):

I got thrift integrated with my project a couple of months back. There are some initialization steps required to obtain the client.

```
  {ok, TFactory} = 
    thrift_socket_transport:new_transport_factory(
      "localhost", 8899, []),
  {ok, PFactory} = 
    thrift_binary_protocol:new_protocol_factory(TFactory, []),
  {ok, Protocol} = PFactory(),
  {ok, Client} = thrift_client:new(Protocol, scribe_thrift),
```

For more context, you can probably take a look at a [module](https://github.com/xslogic/phoebus/blob/master/src/external_store_hdfs.erl) from my git repo.

Comment: The reply from archaelus using thrift_client_util:new is a wrapper for this answer.